# A pole of function in the article of Springer

Tags: power-series

I read the article [Springer, T.A. On the invariant theory of $SU_2$, Indag. Math. 42, 339-345 (1980).](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/1385725880900347) Author considers $\mathbb{C}$-linear map at page $340.$

If $n$ is a positive integer, then write $\zeta^i_n=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$.  For $f \in \mathbb {C}(z)$, put $\tilde{f}(z)=f(z^{-1}).$  Put $g_h(z)=(1-z)^{-h}.$

There are the following lemmas.

> Lemma 1. There is a $\mathbb {C}$-linear map $\varphi_n:\mathbb {C}(z)\rightarrow\mathbb {C}(z)$ such that $$(\varphi_n f) (z^n)=n^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^n{f(\zeta^j_nz}).$$ We have $(\varphi_nf)\tilde{\phantom f}=\varphi_n\tilde{f}$.
>
> Lemma 3. $\varphi_n g_h =\sum_{j=1}^h{\alpha_{nj}g_j}$, where
>   $\alpha_{nh}=n^{h-1}$ and $\alpha_{n,h-1}=-n^{h-2}(n-1) \dfrac{h}{2}$
>   ($h\geq2$).
>
> Lemma 4. Let $f \in \mathbb {C}(z)$. Then the poles of $\phi_n(f)$ are of the form  $\alpha^n$, where $\alpha$ is a pole of $f$. If there is only one pole $\alpha$ of $f$ of maximal order $h$, then there is only one pole of maximal order of $\phi_n(f)$, viz. $\alpha^n$, and its order is also $h$.

Help me prove Lemma 4, please.

There is the following hint:

> Lemma  4  follows  from  lemma  3  by  writing  $f$  as  a  linear  combination  of $g_h(\beta z)$.

I try. Suppose that $f$ has pole of order $h$ at $z=\alpha$. Then the Laurent series of $f$  about $z = \alpha$ is of the form
$f(z)=\sum_{i=-h}^\infty {a_i(\alpha-z)^i}.$
Let $y(z)$ be  the principal part of this Laurent series.
Then
$$
\phi_n(y)=\phi_n\Bigl(\sum_{i=1}^{h} {\frac{a_i}{(\alpha-z)^i}}\Bigr)=\phi_n\Bigl(\sum_{i=1}^{h} {\frac{a_i}{\alpha^h}g_i(\frac{z}{\alpha})}\Bigr)=\sum_{i=1}^{h} {\frac{a_i}{\alpha^h}  \sum_{j=0}^i {b_{nj}g_j(\frac{z}{\alpha})}}.
$$
Using lemma 3 we have that the factor near $(\alpha-z)^{-h}$ is equal to $a_h n^{h-1}.$

At this point I am now stuck.
My english is bad. I will be grateful if someone edit this post.

Answer (score 2):

Lemma 4 doesn't work in the case $\alpha = 0$.  For example, 
$f(z) = 1/z$ has a pole of order $1$ at $z = 0$, but for any $n > 1$ we have
$(\varphi_n f)(z) = 0$ with no poles at all.

Comment: You are  right. But Springer use Lemma 4 for prove proposition 2 in this article for $\alpha=1.$ I suspect that Lemma 4 contains misprint